# Difference between "I'd like to" and "I'd like that"?

Tags: difference, usage, passive-voice, ellipsis

What is the difference between them?

What is the rule for usage of them?

Are they the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could give more complete examples.

"I'd like to ..." could be followed by a description of something that you would like to do. For example, "I'd like to swim the English Channel."

It could also be a response to a question about things that you have done, to express the idea that you have not done it but want to. "Have you ever swum the English Channel?" "No, but I'd like to." Or it could be a positive response to an invitation. "Perhaps you and I could swim the English Channel tomorrow?" "Oh, I'd like to."

"I'd like that." is a complete sentence. It means essentially the same thing as my last example above. "Perhaps you and I could swim the English Channel tomorrow?" "Oh, I'd like that."

Comment: After I'd like to we need a verb? and after I'd like that we need a noun? right or wrong?

Comment: You wouldn't necessarily need a verb if there was an implied verb from previous conversation. "Do you want to visit Bob?" "Yes, I'd like to." But if you began a conversation by saying, "I'd like to", the other person would presumably ask, "You'd like to what?" Whether you need a noun after the verb would depend on the verb. "I'd like to dance" would be perfectly reasonable with no following noun. "I'd like to say" is incomplete. Say what?

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not the same.

One is active and the other is passive.

"I'd like to"...[do X] is the active construction.

"I'd like that"... [Y happens to me] is passive.

Comment: *I'd like that* is not necessarily passive; *that* may be a demonstrative (*We should go out for some fresh air.* / *Yes, I'd like that*).